# Python Model on Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress, forms, user-interface, input

I have a Wordpress site and a python model. Now I would like to connect both. The user should fill in some values or choose from drop down, then hit the submit button. That button click should start my python model that translates the user provided input x into the model calculated output y. That y should then be presented back to the user. What is the best way to do this?